# Splitting string into groups

Tags: string, scala

I'm trying to 'group' a string into segments, I guess this example would explain it more succintly

```
scala> val str: String = "aaaabbcddeeeeeeffg"
... (do something)
res0: List("aaaa","bb","c","dd","eeeee","ff","g")
```

I can thnk of a few ways to do this in an imperative style (with `vars` and stepping through the string to find groups) but I was wondering if any better functional solution could
 be attained? I've been looking through the Scala API but there doesn't seem to be something that fits my needs.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would be helpful if you would mention (and tag) the language(s) you want to work in!

Comment: the post is tagged? Might have taken a while to appear on the SO servers or something

Comment: Do you expect to match `aaabbccddeeffffffhhhhhiiiiijjjj` etc also?  Or just those 7 chars?

Comment: Are builders functional enough for you? The are, of course, mutable in nature, but should be trustworthy since part of standard library.

Comment: I have seen this question, for Scala alone, two or three times already.

Comment: @Daniel With different answers?

Comment: @Thomas Recursion + `span` seems to be a common answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can split the string recursively with span:

```
def s(x : String) : List[String] = if(x.size == 0) Nil else {
    val (l,r) = x.span(_ == x(0))
    l :: s(r) 
}
```

Tail recursive:

```
@annotation.tailrec def s(x : String, y : List[String] = Nil) : List[String] = {
    if(x.size == 0) y.reverse 
    else {
        val (l,r) = x.span(_ == x(0))
        s(r, l :: y)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paul - No, I don't think so.  The match would take more space, and a check against size is pretty clear.  @Thomas - See my comment to Martin Ring's answer.  I like this answer, but I do want to point out the drawbacks of this style of method.

Comment: @Paul You could implement it as Martin has done it. I actually did this but it was not more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't really have much experience with the `span` method so reading something like this has given me some great insight into your thought process behind the solution for this question, so thanks!

Comment: Any ideas how to make this tail recursive? I'm getting stack overflow errors with large inputs

Answer (score 16):

Seems that all other answers are very concentrated on collection operations. But pure string + regex solution is much simpler:

```
str split """(?<=(\w))(?!\1)""" toList
```

In this regex I use **positive lookbehind** and **negative lookahead** for the captured char

Comment: +1 - very nice!  I always forget about the amazing power of regexes.

Comment: And the amazing unreadability. Can you really say you understand that one without careful study.

Comment: Is this "functional"? @Paul That's what comments are for

Comment: @Raphael: I think, that this code is functional. Though I don't think that term "functional" is strictly defined and means the same thing for everybody... or maybe it's better to say that I don't see any reason why this code should be considered imperative or non-functional.

Comment: Is the regex matcher implemented in a functional way? But you are probably right, the term has not been defined sufficiently in this question.

Comment: @Raphael: I think the better question would be whether this code or `split` function are referentially transparent. And they are referentially transparent.

Comment: I was thinking maybe a regex expression might be a good way to approach this but I'm a bit perplexed by the complexity of regular expressions. Whilst the above expression might be succinct it makes no sense to me whatsoever - but thanks for the answer it's certainly very interesting!

Comment: @Raphael, I see no comments :) And I really dislike code that needs a comment just to explain what it does. So yes, regular expressions work, and are good for a codegolf style solution, but I prefer Kernighan and Pike's "say what you mean, simply and directly. "

Comment: @Paul, This code is cryptic only because you are not used to regular expressions. I need to use regular expressions often and I do not need any comment to understand it. Even the solution of Martin Ring needs careful study if you are not used to this style of programming.

Comment: @marcello, but I am familiar with regexps. Why did you assume I am not? I think this use counts as advanced regexp use (lookahead and lookbehind) and will leave most readers behind. I would claim Martin's solution is more comprehensible to more readers.

Comment: @Paul: I agree, but consider this: If you used the above code for real, you would put it in a method, give that a nice name `splitByGroup`, document and unit-test it. The guy who wants to split strings does not have to understand the regex, as long as the implementer of `splitByGroup` does.

Answer (score 13):

```
def group(s: String): List[String] = s match {
  case "" => Nil
  case s  => s.takeWhile(_==s.head) :: group(s.dropWhile(_==s.head))
}
```

---

**Edit:** Tail recursive version:

```
def group(s: String, result: List[String] = Nil): List[String] = s match {
  case "" => result reverse
  case s  => group(s.dropWhile(_==s.head), s.takeWhile(_==s.head) :: result)
}
```

can be used just like the other because the second parameter has a default value and thus doesnt have to be supplied.

Comment: @Rex Kerr why would it be `O(n^2)`? I think there are 2 comparison operations for each character of the string which is less then optimal (better solution is to use `span` like Thomas suggested), but that still is `O(n)` or not? Am i missing something?

Comment: @Rex I'd say you consume every character once (okay actually twice in this implementation). This would be O(n). (Yes, you could make it tail-recursive. This is an exercise not a problem.)

Comment: @Martin, @Thomas - If every character is different, you generate `n` strings of average length `n/2`, for `O(n^2)` work total.

Comment: @Rex Creating a substring of length `k` is `O(1)` and not `O(k)`. (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring))

Comment: @Martin - I'm wrong, but not for the reason you stated; I didn't think that the `dropWhile` managed to make it all the way back to `substring`.  But I checked the source and it looks like it does.  So there's only the stack overflow problem, not the `O(n^2)` problem.

Comment: (Deleted my initial misleading comment.)

Comment: This is certainly the most readable answer I've seen for this and it most definitely my 'accepted' approach to solving my problem. I'm still learning the functional paradigm so it's certainly very beneficial for me to read something like this!

Comment: Any ideas how to make this tail recursive? I'm getting stack overflow errors with large inputs

Answer (score 4):

Make it one-liner:

```
scala>  val str = "aaaabbcddddeeeeefff"
str: java.lang.String = aaaabbcddddeeeeefff

scala> str.groupBy(identity).map(_._2)
res: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(eeeee, fff, aaaa, bb, c, dddd)
```

**UPDATE**:

As @Paul mentioned about the order here is updated version:

```
scala> str.groupBy(identity).toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)
res: List[String] = List(aaaa, bb, c, dddd, eeeee, fff)
```

Comment: I think it's clear from the OP's example that order of the segments matters.

Comment: @Paul The order wasn't mentioned by anyway I updated the code

Comment: this would result in `List(bb, aaa)` for `"aabba"`... wouldnt it? Dont know if that is what djhworld wanted.

Comment: @Martin Ring - Well yeah it will be List(aaa,bb). I guess the way the question was asked it can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, where does this 'identity' thing come from?

Thanks for your answer but it's not quite what I'm after, I'm interesting in the specific order the string comes in in the first place

Comment: `identity` is defined in Predef and always in scope. Its definition is `def identity[A](x: A): A = x`, which simply returns what it was given.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some helper functions like this:

```
val str = "aaaabbcddddeeeeefff"

def zame(chars:List[Char]) = chars.partition(_==chars.head)

def q(chars:List[Char]):List[List[Char]] = chars match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case rest =>
        val (thesame,others) = zame(rest)
        thesame :: q(others)
}

q(str.toList) map (_.mkString)
```

This should do the trick, right? No doubt it can be cleaned up into one-liners even further

Comment: Partition doesn't do what is wanted, I think. Given aaabbbbbaa it will return aaaaa bbbbb

Comment: partition splits the list in two, so splitting "aaaabbbbaaa".toList like this will yield "aaaa","bbbbaaaaa" and then the same function is applied for the remainder of the list in a recursive fashion. I think it does do what you need

Comment: Partition does not split the list at a point. It collects all the elements that match or don't match the predicate `scala> "aaabbbbaaa" partition (_ == 'a')
res0: (String, String) = (aaaaaa,bbbb)

scala>`

Comment: The function you are looking for is `span` (see Thomas' post)

Comment: Yes. You are right, partition is wrong here. Didn't read through the documentation well enough. Thx

Answer (score 1):

A functional* solution using `fold`:

```
def group(s : String) : Seq[String] = {
  s.tail.foldLeft(Seq(s.head.toString)) { case (carry, elem) =>
    if ( carry.last(0) == elem ) {
      carry.init :+ (carry.last + elem)
    }
    else {
      carry :+ elem.toString
    }
  }
}
```

There is a lot of cost hidden in all those sequence operations performed on strings (via implicit conversion). I guess the real complexity heavily depends on the kind of `Seq` strings are converted to.

(*) Afaik all/most operations in the collection library depend in iterators, an imho inherently unfunctional concept. But the code looks functional, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, `List` is now provided with the [`unfold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#unfold[A,S](init:S)(f:S=%3EOption[(A,S)]):CC[A]) builder which can be combined with [`String::span`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#span(p:Char=%3EBoolean):(String,String)):

```
List.unfold("aaaabbaaacdeeffg") {
  case ""   => None
  case rest => Some(rest.span(_ == rest.head))
}
// List[String] = List("aaaa", "bb", "aaa", "c", "d", "ee", "ff", "g")
```

or alternatively, coupled with `Scala 2.13`'s [`Option#unless`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#unless[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A]) builder:

```
List.unfold("aaaabbaaacdeeffg") {
  rest => Option.unless(rest.isEmpty)(rest.span(_ == rest.head))
}
// List[String] = List("aaaa", "bb", "aaa", "c", "d", "ee", "ff", "g")
```

---

Details:

- Unfold (`def unfold[A, S](init: S)(f: (S) => Option[(A, S)]): List[A]`) is based on an internal state (`init`) which is initialized in our case with `"aaaabbaaacdeeffg"`.
- For each iteration, we `span` (`def span(p: (Char) => Boolean): (String, String)`) this internal state in order to find the prefix containing the same symbol and produce a `(String, String)` tuple which contains the prefix and the rest of the string. `span` is very fortunate in this context as it produces exactly what `unfold` expects: a tuple containing the next element of the list and the new internal state.
- The unfolding stops when the internal state is `""` in which case we produce `None` as expected by unfold to exit.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Have to read more carefully. Below is no functional code.

Sometimes, a little mutable state helps:

```
def group(s : String) = {
  var tmp = ""
  val b = Seq.newBuilder[String]

  s.foreach { c =>
    if ( tmp != "" && tmp.head != c ) {
      b += tmp
      tmp = ""
    }

    tmp += c
  }
  b += tmp

  b.result
}
```

Runtime O(n) (if segments have at most constant length) and `tmp.+=` probably creates the most overhead. Use a string builder instead for strict runtime in O(n).

```
group("aaaabbcddeeeeeeffg")
> Seq[String] = List(aaaa, bb, c, dd, eeeeee, ff, g)
```

Comment: If there was some method on `collection.mutable.Seq` that actually *modified* the sequence, you could use a double-linked-list in tmp and be in O(n) time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use scala API you can use the built in function for that:

```
str.groupBy(c => c).values
```

Or if you mind it being sorted and in a list:

```
str.groupBy(c => c).values.toList.sorted
```