# Scala: find all chains in a list

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, sequence, fold

Say I have a list of items:

`Seq(A, B, B, B, B, G, G, S, S, S, B, A, G)`

And I want to find all the chains and get a sequence of them like so:

`Seq(Seq(A), Seq(B, B, B, B), Seq(G, G), Seq(S, S, S), Seq(B), Seq(A), Seq(G))`

I want to maintain order, and use a custom comparison function to decide if two objects are the "same". I'm thinking a fold or a scan may be what I need, but I'm having trouble coming up with the exact case. I'm using Scala.

EDIT: I've modified the answer from that similar question to get this:

```
def collapse(input: Seq[Stmt]): Seq[Seq[Stmt]] = {
    val (l, r) = input.span(_.getClass == input.head.getClass)
    l :: collapse(r)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting string into groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248065/splitting-string-into-groups)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaner solution:

```
  def pack[T](input: List[T]): List[List[T]] =
    input.foldRight(Nil : List[List[T]]) ((e, accu) => accu match {
      case Nil => List(List(e))
      case curList@(h :: t) if e == h => List(e) :: curList
      case curList@(h :: t) => List(List(e)) ::: curList
  })
```

Not using any library functions (ugly):

```
  def pack[T](input: List[T]): List[List[T]] = {
    def packWithPrevious(remaining: List[T])(previous: List[T]): List[List[T]] =
      remaining match {
        case List() => List(previous)
        case head :: tail =>
          val nextIter = packWithPrevious(tail)(_)
          previous match {
            case List() => nextIter(List(head))
            case prevHead :: _ =>
              if (head != prevHead)
                previous :: nextIter(List(head))
              else
                nextIter(head :: previous)
          }
      }
    packWithPrevious(input)(List())
  }

scala> val s = List('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'G', 'G', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'B', 'A', 'G')
s: List[Char] = List(A, B, B, B, B, G, G, S, S, S, B, A, G)

scala> pack(s)
res2: List[List[Char]] = List(List(A), List(B, B, B, B), List(G, G), List(S, S, S), List(B), List(A), List(G))
```

Source: https://github.com/izmailoff/scala-s-99/blob/master/src/main/scala/s99/p09/P09.scala

Test: https://github.com/izmailoff/scala-s-99/blob/master/src/test/scala/s99/p09/P09Suite.scala

Answer (score 1):

Similar to existing answers but I find using a partial function directly in `foldLeft` as a clean solution:

```
val s = Seq("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "G", "G", "S", "S", "S", "B", "A", "G")

s.foldLeft(Seq[Seq[String]]()) {
  case (Seq(), item) => Seq(Seq(item))
  case (head::tail, item) if head.contains(item) => (item +: head) +: tail
  case (seq, item) => Seq(item) +: seq
}.reverse

res0: Seq[Seq[String]] = List(List(A), List(B, B, B, B), List(G, G), List(S, S, S), List(B), List(A), List(G))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider following solution:

```
seq.foldLeft(List(List(seq.head))) { case (acc,item)=> 
  if(acc.head.head==item) (item::acc.head)::acc.tail else List(item)::acc  
}.reverse
```

seq may be empty, so:

```
seq.foldLeft(List(seq.headOption.toList)) { case (acc,item)=> 
  if(acc.head.head==item) (item::acc.head)::acc.tail else List(item)::acc  
}.reverse
```

Comment: What happens if the `seq` is empty?

Comment: Each sublist is backwards, but I can fix that. Thanks. Also I'll add a check for empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I thought `groupBy` would be helpful here, but my solution got slightly  awkward:

```
val seq = Seq("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "G", "G", "S", "S", "S", "B", "A", "G")
val parts = {
  var lastKey: Option[(Int, String)] = None
  seq.groupBy(s => {
    lastKey = lastKey.map((p: (Int, String)) =>
      if (p._2.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) p else (p._1 + 1, s)) orElse Some((0, s))
    lastKey.get
  }).toSeq.sortBy(q => q._1).flatMap(q => q._2)
}
```

(using `equalsIgnoreCase` as example for a comparision function)