# Handling a very Large String Java

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuilder

I am getting a very large `STRING` for server.

**Background:**
Actually I am converting an image into `Base69` string and storing it on my server, than I am calling a service to get back the String. And I am trying to store the String into a `String variable` like this

```
String pic="";
if (payload.substring(i, i+10).equals("<picture >")) {
  for (int j=i+10;j<payload.length();j++) {
    if (payload.substring(j, j+5).equals("</pic")) {
      user.setCountry(country);
      user.setDOB(dob);
      user.setUsername(uname);
      user.setPic(pic);
      users.add(user);
      country="";
      uname="";
      pic="";
      dob="";
      i=j+5;
      break;
    } else {
      pic = pic + payload.substring(j, j+1);
    }
```

But the issue is that after sometime my program crashes and I did not get complete String into the variable `pic`

Is there a way to handle very long strings coming from the server? I mean to say how can I get the same `Base64` String in my variable `pic` completely so that I decode it back to the picture.

Comment: are there errors/exceptions being thrown?

Comment: You could use StringBulder like it says in your tags, not a String as it says in your code. But I don't see any reason to build up 'pic' at all. Just compute its start and end indexes, and use 'payload.substring(start, end+1)' to create it when you find the end: which in turn you should do with indexOf() rather than your own loop.

Comment: You do not need to convert to base64 to store in database. You can store image as blob. Then you can return it as byte array. You can also convert it to base64 before sending it.

Comment: @BobMalooga sorry, its Base64.

Comment: @mangusta when i am sending the base64 string i am storing the whole string into one string variable. so when i am getting it back from server i am trying same, than why do i need to increase the heap size? just asking

Comment: @EJP good point, let me do it your way

Comment: Are you trying to write a makeshift XML parser? Don't. research javax.xml.parsers

Comment: parsing is not an issue, i just want to store a very large string

Comment: @HassaanRabbani sorry, this part "storing it on my server" of your question ran out of my attention

Answer (score 1):

Find the end of what you want with something like:

```
int endPos = payload.indexOf("</pic>", currentPos);
```

and then do **one** substring that take the full picture data:

```
String pic = payload.substring(currentPos, endPos);
```

Comment: 'endPos+1'. The second augment is the first index to exclude.

Comment: @EJP Actually no - this code: `String payload = "<pic>base64</pic>";
 int currentPos = 5; int endPos = payload.indexOf("</pic>", currentPos); String pic = payload.substring(currentPos, endPos); 
System.out.println(pic);`

Prints: base64

Comment: by the way i have already solved the issue this way +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that the code in the `if` statement seems unrelated to the string at hand,  you have [String concatenation in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat) in your else statement, which kills performance.

Another point of concern is your abuse of `substring()`, see [Time complexity of Java's substring()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring) (Maybe consider converting the string to an Array or stream?)