# Logic of compareTo in Java (Role of offset)

Tags: java, string, offset, compareto

```
public class CustomString {
    public char value[];
    public int offset;
    public int count;
    public int hash;
}


CustomString one = new CustomString();
char valueOne[] = {'A','N'};
one.count = 2;
one.hash = 0;
one.offset = 0;
one.value = valueOne;

CustomString two = new CustomString();
char valueTwo[] = {'F','A','N'};
two.count = 3;
two.hash = 0;
two.offset =1;
two.value = valueTwo;

compareTo(one,two)
```

**compareTo method of String:**

```
public static int compareTo(CustomString one, CustomString two) {
    int len1 = one.count;
    int len2 = two.count;
    int n = Math.min(len1, len2);
    char v1[] = one.value;
    char v2[] = two.value;
    int i = one.offset;
    int j = two.offset;

    if (i == j) {
        int k = i;
        int lim = n + i;
        while (k < lim) {
            char c1 = v1[k];
            char c2 = v2[k];
            if (c1 != c2) {
                return c1 - c2;
            }
            k++;
        }
    } else {
        while (n-- != 0) {
            char c1 = v1[i++];
            char c2 = v2[j++];
            if (c1 != c2) {
                return c1 - c2;
            }
        }
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

Since for "FAN" I have used offset as 1,I thought "AN" of "FAN" will be compared with "AN" and return 0.But it did not since `compareTo` of `String` returns `return len1 - len2;`

My question is,what is the purpose of `offset` in `compareTo` method? Always offset is 0.Can you also please give an example by having a different offset for either or both?

Comment: Are you talking about java.lang.String? What is CustomString? Is this your code or someone elses?

Comment: Yes.I was talking about java.lang.String.I wanted to debug `compareTo` by changing the offset to something other than 0.So I wrote a own class `CustomString` to simulate `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 3):

If this is meant to mimic pre-Java7 `java.lang.String`, the `offset` field is used to implement a constant-time `substring()` operation. See [Time complexity of Java's substring()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring)

To relate this to your example, `"FAN".substring(1, 3)` would set `count` to `2`, not `3`:

```
CustomString two = new CustomString();
char valueTwo[] = {'F','A','N'};
two.value = valueTwo;
two.offset = 1;
two.count = 2; // <------- the number of characters in the string "AN"
```

Thus, `one.compareTo(two)` would evaluate to `0` (since `len1 == len2 == 2`).