# Java complexity of two recursive methods

Tags: java, recursion, methods, complexity-theory

```
public static String rec1 (String s) {

    int n = s.length()/2; 
    return n==0 ? s : rec1(s.substring(n)) + rec1(s.substring(0,n)); 
}


public static String rec2 (String s) {
    return s.length()<=1 ? s : rec2(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0); 
}
```

Why is the complexity of `rec2` greater than `rec1`?

I've done 10.000 iterations on each and measured the execution time using System.nanoTime() with the following results:

```
rec1: Stringlength: 200  Avgtime: 19912ns Recursive calls: 399

rec1: Stringlength: 400  Avgtime: 42294 ns Recursive calls: 799

rec1: Stringlength: 800  Avgtime: 77674 ns Recursive calls: 1599

rec1: Stringlength: 1600 Avgtime: 146305 ns Recursive calls: 3199

rec2: Stringlength: 200  Avgtime: 26386 ns Recursive calls: 200

rec2: Stringlength: 400  Avgtime: 100677 ns Recursive calls: 400

rec2: Stringlength: 800  Avgtime: 394448 ns Recursive calls: 800

rec2: Stringlength: 1600 Avgtime: 1505853 ns Recursive calls: 1600
```

So at a stringlength of 1600 rec1 is 10x faster than rec2. I'm looking towards a brief explanation.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that the complexity of rec2 is > rec1?  Put a print statement in each method and trying running them.  For instance, `rec1("1234")`  makes 7 calls whereas `rec2("1234")` makes 4.

Comment: Check my edit above, i measured the time using System.nanoTime and trying to figure the reason why rec2 is faster than rec1. ( Even disabled speedstep )

Comment: My original answer was wrong. I've now updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Time complexity of Java's substring()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring), `String#substring` now copies the backing array, so has `O(n)` time complexity.

Using this fact it can be seen that `rec1` has time complexity `O(n log n)` whereas `rec2` has time complexity `O(n^2)`.

Start with an initial `String s = "12345678"`. For simplicity I have taken the length to be a power of 2.

**`rec1`:**

1. `s` is split into `"1234"` and `"5678"`.
2. These are split into `"12"`, `"34"`, `"56"`, `"78"`
3. These are split into `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, `"4"`, `"5"`, `"6"`, `"7"`, `"8"`

There are 3 steps here because `log(8) = 3`. Every `char` is copied in every step, so the total number of copied characters is `O(n log n)`. When the `String` is reassembled in reverse order, the above `Strings` are now joined together using concatenation, using the following steps:

1. Strings are joined into `"21"`, `"43"`, `"65"`, `"87"`
2. Strings are joined into `"4321"`, `"8765"`
3. Strings are joined to make `"87654321"`.

This another total of `O(n log n)` copied characters!

**`rec2`:**

1. `s` is split into `"1"` and `"2345678"`.
2. `"2345678"` is split into `"2"` and `"345678"`.
3. `"345678"` is split into `"3"` and `"45678"`.
4. `"45678"` is split into `"4"` and `"5678"`.
5. `"5678"` is split into `"5"` and `"678"`.
6. `"678"` is split into `"6"` and `"78"`.
7. `"78"` is split into `"7"` and `"8"`.

This is a total of `8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 = 35` copied characters. If you know algebra, this will be `(n * (n+1)) / 2 - 1` copied characters in general, so `O(n^2)`.

When this is all assembled in reverse order, the number of copies characters will be `O(n^2)` again.

Comment: How did you get to O(n log n)? The recursion is called *twice* in each level. That cancels out the log n, and the total complexity is linear in the number of recursion, multiplied by the copies of the characters.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm reasonably confident I'm right, but I'm going to do some tests to check...

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. Im not sure either if it's O(n) or O(n log n)

Comment: You're right, and I've corrected my answer accordingly. The key is that each character is copied *depth* times, regardless of the number of recursion steps.

Answer (score 3):

(This is a corrected version regarding time complexity)

Although the number of recursions is actually linear in n (because the recursion is called *twice* at each level) there is a difference between the two methods as far as copying the characters is concerned.

Each of the methods is internally doing two copy operations - one for the `substring` (in Java 7), and one for the `concat` (represented by the `+` operator).

In `rec2`, it copies the right side of the string again and again all the way until only one character remains. So the last character in the string is copied *depth* times, and the depth is linear. So linear steps multiplied by linear copies (it's actually a series) gives O(n<sup>2</sup>).

In `rec1`, each character gets either copied to the left substring or the right substring. But no character is copied more than *depth* times - until we get to the single-character substrings. So each character is copied log n times. Although the recursion is called twice, it is not called on the same characters, so the cancellation of the log caused by the double call does not affect the number of copies of each character.

The same is true for the re-construction. The same copies take place in reverse.

Number of copies - n characters multiplied by *depth* of log n, gives O(n log n). Number of steps performed - O(n), so the number of steps is less significant than the number of copies, and the total of the complexity is O(n log n).

---

In addition, there is space complexity. `rec1` goes to a depth of O(log n) in its recursion, that is, it takes stack space of O(log n). It does so twice, but that doesn't change the big-O. In contrast, `rec2` goes to a depth of O(n).

On my machine, running the two methods with a string of length 16384 resulted in a stack overflow for `rec2`. `rec1` finished without a problem. Of course this varies based on your JVM settings, but you get the picture.

Comment: I needed some visual aid to better understand the question and the finer points in your answer, so I printed the recursive calls: http://pastebin.com/WAipHBYE Maybe it can help other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's investigate the performance difference:

```
String.substring()
```

- substring is really cheap in java (up until Java 7 Update 6) cause it doesn't copy the raw data but only updates offsets on the same array.

String overriden `+` operator

- here comes the difference cause overriden `+` operator uses `StringBuilder` in case of non-literal strings. If you drill down the implementation of `StringBuilder.append()` method you will finally find a call to `System.arraycopy()`.

So the difference is that `System.arraycopy()` is dealing with exponentially decreasing array size in `rec1` while only with linearly decreasing array size in `rec2`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I  measured the execution time of both methods with different length and they behave differently on longer strings, im looking for a reason for this behaviour.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but according to Jon Skeet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring `subString` does now copy the raw data.

Comment: i'm currently running JDK 1.7.0.04 and in this version there's no copying for `subString`. So the difference on my Java version comes mostly from System.arraycopy()