# Do String methods in Java run in O(1) time?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, big-o

This is my code to find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters. Does this code run in O(n) time? Or does it run in O(n^2) time? I am not sure if the String methods run in O(n) time or O(1) time.

A test case includes: "pwwkewo" returning 4 because "kewo" is the the longest substring inside the string that has unique characters.

```
public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {

    int maxLength = 0;
    String sub = "";

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {

         //add that char to the sub string
         sub = sub + s.charAt(i);

        //if we find a char in our string
        if(sub.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) != -1) {

           //drop any replicated indexes before it
            sub = sub.substring(sub.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) + 1);
        }

        if(sub.length() > maxLength) {
            maxLength = sub.length();
        }


    }

    return maxLength;

}
```

Comment: i'd guess its O(n) because the more characters you have, the longer it takes

Comment: Won't it be O(N^2) because `sub.indexOf()` is O(N)? BTW, `sub = sub + s.charAt(i);` makes for a very inefficient loop as there's a lot of excess memory allocation - look at `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Depends on your Java version. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring

Answer (score 7):

`sub.indexOf()` can take linear time, since it might have to check all the characters of `sub`. And the length of `sub` is **O(n)** in the worst case (assuming your input has no repeating characters).

Therefore your total running time is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, since the loop has `n` iterations and in each iteration you call `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs in `O(n^2)` as there is a `for` loop and inside it you call an `indexOf()` method. This in turn is `O(n)`.

Thus your method is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: And there are more O(n) operations in the loop: `sub = sub + s.charAt(i);` (better use `StringBuilder`), `sub.substring(...)` (in later Java releases, this creates a copy of the characters). And doing `sub.indexOf(s.charAt(i)` twice also is a waste of time, but doesn't influence the Big-O classification.