# Time complexity of Stringbuilder subSequence method

Tags: java, time-complexity

Since Java 7, String substring method has changed its big O from O(1) to O(n).

What is the time complexity of StringBuilder subSequence method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `java-11-openjdk`, `AbstractStringBuilder.subSequence` calls `substring`...

```
public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
    return substring(start, end);
}
```

... which is almost identical to the method of the same name of `String` ...

```
public String substring(int start, int end) {
    checkRangeSIOOBE(start, end, count);
    if (isLatin1()) {
        return StringLatin1.newString(value, start, end - start);
    }
    return StringUTF16.newString(value, start, end - start);
}
```

... calling `newString` which will (in both cases) copy the backing array, so it's  O(n), too.

```
public static String newString(byte[] val, int index, int len) {
    return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(val, index, index + len),
                      LATIN1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you have found this info. O(1) to O(n) for substring?

The complexity for `StringBuilder.subSequence(int start, int end)` will roughly be the same as for `String.substring(int start, int end)`.

`StringBuilder.subSequence(int, int)` actually calls `AbstractStringBuilder.substring(int, int)` which calls  `public String(char value[], int offset, int count)` to create the result.

`String.substring(int start, int end)` uses the same constructor.

So all the methods have the same implementation.

The work is done in the string construtor. It uses `System.arrayCopy` to copy the chars from one buffer to the other. So it is not doing an assignment for each single character (which would make it O(n), where n is not the length of the input, but the length of the substring), but using a high-performance system function to copy a block of memory, which is a lot better than O(n).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679746/time-complexity-of-javas-substring
Prior to Java 7, it used same char[] so the cost is the time taken to perform validation and construct a single new string O(1).

Comment: But even if `System.arrayCopy` is very fast, it is still O(n), right?