# Longest common prefix based on elements

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of string elements in an array:

```
["000", "1110", "01", "001", "110", "11"]
```

For an element in the array,

- I want to find the previous element index with longest common prefix.
- If I have multiple matching elements then select the nearest element
  index.
- If none found then just select previous index.

**Example:**

```
["000", "1110", "01", "001", "110", "11"]

Output:
[0,1,1,1,2,5]

a) "000" - output is 0, because we do not have any previous elements.
b) "1110" - output is 1, no previous element with longest prefix so select previous index.
c) "01" - output is 1,"000" has longest prefix, so its index is 1.
d) "001" - output is 1, "000" has longest prefix, so its index is 1.
e) "110" - output is 2,  "1110" has longest prefix, so its index 2.
f) "11" - output 5, "110" is most nearest element with longest prefix so its index 5.
```

I am not able to understand what approach I need to take for this task. Can you please help me.

Comment: Is it correct that in your example you start indexing from 1 and not 0? Why is your `commonPrefix` returning a String and not a `int[]` or `List<Integer>` as you have shown in your example?

Comment: yes starting index is 1. I am starting with existing code I have in geekforgeeks, but that is not the correct approach to follow, so got stuck where to start.

Comment: What you are trying to do in each method is different than what the method comment and signature says. I presume these were already prepared for you, do you understand those comments?

Comment: commonPrefixUtil looks good but you are not using it right

Comment: @Hawk, I have added another code now to my post, but its time complexity is more, how to improve this now.

Answer (score 1):

## Naive solution based on the former question

`commonPrefix` is supposed to (according to the comment) the longest prefix in the array up to index n. What does that mean? You need to calculate all prefixes and pick the longest.

```java
static String commonPrefix(String arr[], int n) {
    String longestPrefix = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        final String currentPrefix = commonPrefixUtil(arr[i], arr[n]);
        if (currentPrefix.length() > longestPrefix.length()) {
            longestPrefix = currentPrefix;
        }
    }
    return longestPrefix;
}
```

So that would yield `"00"` for `arr = ["000", "1110", "01", "001", "110", "11"]; n = 3`.

Now that we have the longest prefix, what? We need to find the closest index to `n` that starts with that prefix...

```java
static int closestIndex(String[] arr, String longestPrefix, int n) {
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i].startsWith(longestPrefix)) {
            return i + 1; // + 1 because the solution wants starting index with 1
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How to put it together? Just call the two methods for each input

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = { "000", "1110", "01", "001", "110", "11" };
    int[] output = new int[words.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        final String longestPrefix = commonPrefix(words, i);
        output[i] = closestIndex(words, longestPrefix, i);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}
```

---

You have deleted your `commonPrefixUtil` implementation that worked from the question, so I add my own:

```java
static String commonPrefixUtil(String str1, String str2) {
    int shorterStringLength = Math.min(str1.length(), str2.length());
    int length = 0;
    for (; length < shorterStringLength; length++) {
        if (str1.charAt(length) != str2.charAt(length)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return str1.substring(0, length);
}
```

---

## Optimalized solution

I created a new solution using dynamic programming with tabulation (if I understand correctly), that is I use a hashmap of already all prefixes pointing to the indexes of the words where the prefix is from. The value of the Map is a sorted tree, so it can be really easily determined which word with the common prefix is closest to the current index. The HashMap ensures constant-time operations and the TreeSet guarantees log(n) time cost.

Explained more simply, I process the first letter of all words, and then the next etc. During this process I memorise where all prefix substrings are, while they are automatically sorted. I stop the loop after processing the last letter of the longest word.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = { "000", "1110", "01", "001", "110", "11" };

    int[] result = new int[words.length];
    final int firstWordLength = words.length > 0 ? words[0].length() : 8;
    // prefix -> [indexes of prefix occurrence]
    HashMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>> prefixes = new HashMap<>(words.length * (firstWordLength + 1) * 2);
    int wordLength = 1;
    boolean isUpdatedResult;
    do { // O(k)
        isUpdatedResult = false;
        for (int wordIdx = 0; wordIdx < words.length; wordIdx++) { // O(n)
            if (words[wordIdx].length() < wordLength) {
                continue;
            }
            final String currentPrefix = words[wordIdx].substring(0, wordLength); // Java >= 7 update 6 ? O(k) : O(1)
            final TreeSet<Integer> prefixIndexes = prefixes.get(currentPrefix); // O(1)
            if (prefixIndexes != null) {
                // floor instead of lower, because we have put `wordIdx + 1` inside
                final Integer closestPrefixIndex = prefixIndexes.floor(wordIdx); // O(log n)
                if (closestPrefixIndex != null) {
                    result[wordIdx] = closestPrefixIndex;
                    isUpdatedResult = true;
                }
            }
            // take the previous index for the result if no match
            if (result[wordIdx] == 0) {
                result[wordIdx] = wordIdx;
            }
            final TreeSet<Integer> newPrefixIndexes = prefixes.computeIfAbsent(currentPrefix, p -> new TreeSet<>()); // O(1)
            // the result index must be + 1
            newPrefixIndexes.add(wordIdx + 1); // O(log n)
        }
        wordLength++;
    } while (isUpdatedResult);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

I have marked all the operations with their big O time complexity. `n` is the number of words in the input array, i.e. `words.length` and `k` is the length of the longest word. According to [Jon Skeet's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4679775/9274948) the time complexity of substring has changed in Java 7 update 6 to linear.

So we can calculate:

```
O(k) * O(n) * (O(log n) + O(k))
```

Hopefully, the code is understandable and I calculated the complexity correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but we have almost 4 loops, can the time complexity be reduced?

Comment: I have created a more optimalized solution, please check it out :)

Comment: `prefixes.get(currentPrefix)` is Theta(k), not O(1).

Comment: You should use `prefixes.computeIfAbsent(currentPrefix, k -> new TreeSet<>())` insted of `prefixes.getOrDefault(currentPrefix, new TreeSet<>())`

Answer (score 1):

Using a trie makes it pretty easy to find the longest common prefix so far in time linear in the total number of characters in the input. In Python (sorry):

```
import collections


class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self._children = collections.defaultdict(Trie)
        self._previous_index = 0

    # Find the longest prefix of word that appears in the trie,
    # return the value of _previous_index at that node.
    def previous_index(self, word):
        node = self
        for letter in word:
            child = node._children.get(letter)
            if child is None:
                break
            node = child
        return node._previous_index

    # Ensure that each of the prefixes of word exists in the trie.
    # At each node corresponding to a prefix, set its _previous_index to index.
    def insert(self, index, word):
        self._previous_index = index
        node = self
        for letter in word:
            node = node._children[letter]
            node._previous_index = index


def longest_common_prefix_indexes(words):
    trie = Trie()
    for index_minus_one, word in enumerate(words):
        print(trie.previous_index(word))
        trie.insert(index_minus_one + 1, word)


longest_common_prefix_indexes(["000", "1110", "01", "001", "110", "11"])
```

Comment: can you please add comments so I will try to do this in Java

Comment: Can you please check your claim about the linear complexity? I think the code you have shown is O(n*k) (insert for each word, for each letter). And I don't know what is the complexity of get (from a quick search I see  O(key_length) but really not sure).

Comment: @Hawk linear in the number of letters, not the number of words.

Comment: @Hawk get is constant-time (for sure if we assume an O(1)-size alphabet, but in a randomized sense for larger alphabets).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you

This is funcion that returns the length of the longest common prefix of two Strings:

```
int commonPrefixLength(String s, String t) {
    if (s.length() == 0 || t.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int commonPrefixLength = 0;
    int shorter = Math.min(s.length(), t.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < shorter; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(i)) {
            break;
        }
        commonPrefixLength++;
    }

    return commonPrefixLength;
}
```

For every string in array you can check previous strings and choose the one with to longest common prefix:

```
    //indexing from 1
    String[] strings = new String[] {"", "000", "1110", "01", "001", "110", "11"};

    for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
        int longestCommonPrefix = 0;
        int answer = 0;

        //for every previous string
        for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            int commonPrefix = commonPrefixLength(strings[j], strings[i]);
            if (commonPrefix > longestCommonPrefix) {
                longestCommonPrefix = commonPrefix;
                answer = j;
            }
        }

        //no common prefix found
        if (answer == 0) {
            answer = i - 1;
        }

        System.out.println(answer);
    }
```